# Almost singing themselves they run

Tags: meaning

'

> Our Fathers of Old'
>        Excellent herbs had our fathers of old--
>        Excellent herbs to ease their pain--
>        Alexanders and Marigold,
>        Eyebright, Orris, and Elecampane
> ,
>        Basil, Rocket, Valerian, Rue,
>        (**Almost singing themselves they run**)
>        Vervain, Dittany, Call-me-to-you--
>        Cowslip, Melilot, Rose of the Sun.

This is 'Our Fathers of Old' by Kipling. 
https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/our_fathers_of_old.html
I can not understand the meaning of the sentence below. 
Almost singing themselves they run
I am glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

The poet celebrates the 'musical' quality of the names: as they 'run' (move swiftly forward) they seem, in and by themselves, without regard to context, to 'sing': fall naturally into a poetic line.